# Can't load JS file in loaded jquery div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've three files, index.html contain global.js file and jquery. in global.js file I call `clickme` button in other file. but it wont work when loaded in index.html. I want to when click me button load in index.html also load global.js to work perfectly click me alert.

**index.html:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>

    <script src="global.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**global.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".loader").load("other.html");
    $(".clickme").bind("click", function () {
        alert("Done!");
    })
});
```

**other.html:**

```
<button class="clickme">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: `.bind()` has been deprecated for years, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: You're binding the handler before the `other.html` code has been loaded, since `.load()` is asynchronous. Either move the call to `.bind()` into the `.load()` callback function, or use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)